# Django staticfiles 404 in Deploy to Digital Ocean

Tags: django, digital-ocean, django-staticfiles

The server is launched on Ubuntu 16.04.2 x64 on the local server all works with the same settings as only started here, can not find them!

settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    #'/var/www/static/',

]

STATIC_ROOT     = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_cdn")
MEDIA_URL       = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT      = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media_cdn")
```

urls

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^chart/', include("charts.urls", namespace='charts')),
    url(r'^comments/', include("comments.urls", namespace='comments')),
    url(r'^im/', include("messenger.urls", namespace='im')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include("accounts.urls", namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^series/', include("serials.urls", namespace='series')),
    url(r'^', include("serials.urls", namespace='homeview')),




]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

on local server everything works great, but when i launch it in live staticfiles not found

```
> [29/Jul/2017 07:54:38] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1"
> 404 102 [29/Jul/2017 07:54:38] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js
> HTTP/1.1" 404 100 [29/Jul/2017 07:54:38] "GET
> /static/min_css/base.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 101 [29/Jul/2017 07:54:38]
> "GET /static/js/Chart.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 96 [29/Jul/2017 07:54:38]
> "GET /static/js/smooth-scroll.js HTTP/1.1" 404 100 [29/Jul/2017
> 07:54:38] "GET /static/js/script.js HTTP/1.1" 404 93 [29/Jul/2017
> 07:54:39] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 100
> [29/Jul/2017 07:54:39] "GET /static/js/Chart.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 96
> [29/Jul/2017 07:54:39] "GET /static/js/smooth-scroll.js HTTP/1.1" 404
> 100 [29/Jul/2017 07:54:39] "GET /static/js/script.js HTTP/1.1" 404 93
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must make staticfiles for deploy like this!
replace you staticfiles const in your setting, and everything gonna be great!

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

]

MEDIA_URL    = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = '../static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '../media/'
```

if it does'nt work use full path!
like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/static/',
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you haven't run `python manage.py collectstatic`. That will copy your static files to the right location.

If that doesn't work, check your web server configuration.

Comment: how to cheack server configuration?

Comment: What web server are you using? Nginx or Apache?

Comment: i  using  Nginx server

Comment: Ok, can you post the Nginx config? Should be at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` unless you have set it up elsewhere.

Comment: I'm trying to go through that path that you gave, but it leaves an error that there is no such directory, there is only / etc /

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. You say you're on Ubuntu 16.04? And presumably you installed Nginx using apt-get?

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`? Does nano open it?

Comment: nope, [ Directory '/etc/nginx/sites-available' does not exist ]

Comment: Well, that's the default location. Does `/etc/nginx` exist and what directories are underneath it?

Comment: sorry just by the tutorial when he launch on this stage everything is work, but only on the next video he install nginx

Comment: Basically, you should have a location set up for the static directory. The Nginx config at https://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2014/10/19/my-django-web-server-setup/ is what I normally use as a starting point.